# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types even with Copy Local

Tags: c#, reference

I have an internal report on my web application which when I browse to it locally displays as expected. I am using a `rdlc` and `xsd` with a standard `apsx` web page to render the report.

I have now deployed to my staging server and when I try to browse to the page which displays the report I am getting:

```
An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Locally, I have added a Reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` by browsing to:

> C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91

And I have set it to `Copy Local` and can see the `.dll` in the bin folder on the staging server, however I'm still getting the error message.

Out of interest I copied the `.dll` from my local machine, and ftp'd it to the staging server and into the bin folder. It then worked, temporarily until I did another commit, which wiped the bin folder and the error returned.

Its like the version of `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` is out of date on the staging server's OS perhaps?

What's going on here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's probably looking for `one of its dependencies` if you're sure the dll is in the bin folder.

Instead of referencing from the GAC have you tried removing the reference and adding the following NuGet package ?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/

Comment: Just the job, mucho's gracias

Answer (score 24):

Same issue for me, however the problem was that the binding redirects in the app.config had not been updated to the new version. Usually updating the nuget package does it automatically, but this nuget package was in a referenced project. Simple fix:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings />
  <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <!-- <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" /> -->
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I had to manually add the above assemblyBinding entry to my web.config file, despite the fact that I had Microsoft.SqlServer.Types referenced by the nuget package. It seems that the web app was trying to load an older version from the GAC instead of the one I have referenced.

Comment: Same here, I had no references in my web.config but once I added the dependentAssembly it worked

Answer (score 3):

I copied the file

> **My_Solution_Dir)\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.14.0.314.76\lib\net40\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll**

into the "**/bin**" directory.
And my problem is solved.

Comment: In my case this file should have come it self during publish but somehow didn't copy in BIN folder. This file copied itself in BIN When I again created the publish.

Comment: I had to do the same thing. The only difference the version was 11.0.0.0. Once I copied the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.11.0.0.0 from packages folder into the Bin, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Experienced the same issue, that has occured after upgrading of Visual Studio and Sql Server instances.

Problem has gone after download and reinstallation of

- [SQLSysClrtypes.msi](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100451) and
- ReportViewer.msi packages,

Hope it could help someone.

Comment: Re-installing the SQLSysCLRTypes.msi solved the problem for me, but the link above doesn't take you to the right page. As of 5/1/22, the correct url is https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100451

Comment: I added the link Avi provided. This [link could be the ReportViewer.msi](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=45496) but i have not tried it myself yet.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get my program to compile on the new workstation, by using the following code

```
    <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
```

**The issue?** The SQL Express server that Microsoft was offering by default, changed from 2017 to 2019 during that time and I never noticed, so the **newVersion** had to be set as **newVersion="15.0.0.0"**.

Comment: comment this section :

<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding> 

works for me

Answer (score 0):

After installing the nuget package, copy the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll from
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
to BIN folder of my web application in my Host web server.

Answer (score 0):

In the Web.config file, just change the `oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0"` to `oldVersion="14.0.0.0-14.0.0.0"`
at the same version that actually you have installed.

In the section >runtime>:
`<dependentAssembly> <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" /> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" /> </dependentAssembly>`