# How do I connect to sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to connect my database, SQL Server 2012, from Visual Studio 2015 and when I add the data source to the project I always get the error below. Can anyone please help me?

[image: the error picture is down below]

Comment: have you tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30460124/10763029)?

Comment: Try adding Microsoft.SqlServer.Types nuget package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types even with Copy Local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454099/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-types-even-with-copy-local)

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your app.config file and modify your startup tag to add this attribute.

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
 <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```